# resultSet.getInt() return value on a string containing two ints

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I need to parse the value of a database column that generally contains integers, based on the result Set generated from a JDBC call. However, one particular row of the column has two integers in it (ie, "48, 103"). What will be the return value of resultSet.getInt() on that column?

Comment: What is the definition of the column in the database - some kind of `varchar`?

Comment: Eng.Fouad - I'm currently solving a few other problems that are stopping me from being to test it immediately - trying to get ahead of the curve by asking here first.

Comment: How can 2 rows returned by one `select` statement differ in its number of columns?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: The select statement returns one row in particular. However, most rows in the column only contain one number in a string - the row that I need to work with has two numbers separated by a comma.

The DBMS that I am using is MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will throw an exception.

I think you are taking the wrong approach here. The `getXXX()` is supposed to match the data type of the table. Is the data type on the table listed as VARCHAR? If that case you should use [getString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) to get the data and then parse it with the [String.spilt(",")](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) if the `,` exists (you can use [String.indexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to verify is the comma is there or not).

Comment: This sounds right. Thanks for the feedback - I'm updating some existing code so maybe the getInt worked before when they knew they were only dealing with one value in the column.

Comment: @DaveWeber - you are welcome. Do you have access to see the schema for the table? Validate what the data type is listed there as.

Comment: I should have access (it's a syscolumns table), will try to do so later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You'll almost certainly get a `SQLException` (or possibly a `NumberFormatException`).  The actual [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) just says that the result set will return "the value of the designated column... as an `int`".  The exact details will be implementation-specific, but I doubt you'll get anything sensible from a value of `"48, 103"`.

(Personally I think it's an error if the driver lets you call `getInt` on that column in any case, even for "sensible" values.  A string is not an int, even if it's a string representation of an int, and the conversion should be done manually by the developer.)

Comment: I'd think NumberFormat is more likely, as SQLExceptions only occur on database access error. It's grabbing the value fine, it's just an issue with parsing the number. But I do think you're correct about the getInt part not working on text columns.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to throw an exception. If it does give you a value, it won't be what you want. I'd get the values as strings and parse them, splitting on commas and trimming spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a `NumberFormatException`.